# How to store cached information by a plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, browser-cache

I'm on a firefox plugin development. By the way I want to store some information from documents which are loaded by the browser. And also some information given by the user about the webpage (like, **do this page contains explicit contents? (yes/no)**) through my javascript code. These information should be stored in some place so that I can warn/alert the user about the content of the webpage he/she about to load like, **You are about to view a webpage with more than 50% advertisement**.In short my question is **Where do normal firefox plugin store cached data?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple storage built into the browser. You start with this commands:

```
var pref = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
```

Then you can save data into like this:

```
pref.setCharPref("freelayer.mydata", mydataold + mydatanew);
```

Then you can read that data with:

```
var mydata = pref.getCharPref("freelayer.mydata").split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to persist the data? [*SQLite*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/storage) should do it. If your data is highly connected to web pages, then [*places annotations*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Places_annotation_service) might be another option.